# Linear regression not applying to loglog scale with seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, loglog

I am currently trying to do a linear regression on a loglog plot using seaborn.
Currently it tries to do the linear regression on the normal scale even though the data is shown plotted in loglog scale.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = x**2.0
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y})
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
ax.set(xscale="log", yscale="log")
sns.regplot("x", "y", data, ax=ax)
```

[image: Example 1]

The only work around that I have been able to do is to log x and y in advance of plotting but then the scale for the x and y are no longer nice compared to the code above.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import seaborn as sns

x = np.arange(1, 10)
y = x**2.0
data = pd.DataFrame(data={'x': x, 'y': y})
data=np.log(data)
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 7))
sns.regplot("x", "y", data)
```

[image: Example 2]

Is there a way to keep the loglog scale from the first example of code but have the linear regression apply to the loglog scale and not to the normal scale?